# Abbreviations like MWV, MW, etc

Tags: discussion

I see the list of common abbreviations, but neither of the following are on it:

> Most would argue that 'chance upon', though a MWV, is MW

Is there a second list on the site, or elsewhere, that might help with this?

Comment: Could you please say where this line is from? The context would help, and the answer will be added to the original list (so that it's all in one place)

Comment: Found it here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112081/to-investigate-something-new

Comment: @LukeBaumgarten: I have absolutely no idea what those abbreviations could mean. I suspect them to be far from common. I have asked the commenter in that thread to explain them.

Comment: This is far Too Localised.

Comment: That's cool. I was just trying to pick up whatever jargon I might be missing

Comment: From context I'd say MWV is "multi-word verb" (phrasal verb). You'd have to ask Edwin Ashworth to know exactly what point he was trying to make.

Comment: Unquestionably MWV is [Multi-Word Verb](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=e1s6uGQzAsMC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=mwv+language+grammar+linguistics&source=bl&ots=A6ZG-ZkUCE&sig=qvDVWz2TRHHYmlm_cSrogtE14oc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IPykUZWGGoaM0AWqxIBI&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=mwv%20language%20grammar%20linguistics&f=false), but it's hardly so commonplace we should include it in an ELU glossary.